# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and have to build an application to get historical data from Twitter. I can see the tweets in my console and all the information I need! 
But the problem I have now is that I need to write this information to a .csv file but I encounter the following error while running the code:
`"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"`. I know that the problem is that the Tweets I'm collecting are written in Swedish so its a frequent use of the letter `"ÅÄÖ"`. 
Can anyone please help me with this or have any pointers as to where i should start looking for a solution?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from TwitterSearch import *
import csv

import codecs





try:
    tuo = TwitterUserOrder('Vismaspcs') # create a TwitterUserOrder


    ts = TwitterSearch(
        consumer_key = '',
        consumer_secret = '',
        access_token = '',
        access_token_secret = ''
    )

    # start asking Twitter about the timeline
    for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tuo):
        print( '@%s tweeted: %s' % ( tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text']) )
        print (tweet['created_at'],tweet['favorite_count'],tweet ['retweet_count'])




    with open('visma.csv','w') as fout:
        writer=csv.writer(fout)    
        writer.writerows([tweet['user']['screen_name'],tweet['text'],tweet['created_at'],tweet['favorite_count'],tweet['retweet_count']])



except TwitterSearchException as e: # catch all those ugly errors
    print(e)
```

Comment: I guess you are using Python 3?

Answer (score 2):

The csv module cannot handle unicode in python2:

> Note This version of the csv module doesn't support Unicode input. Also, there are currently some issues regarding ASCII NUL characters. Accordingly, all input should be UTF-8 or printable ASCII to be safe; see the examples in section Examples.

You can use `tweet['user']['screen_name'].encode("utf-8")`...

Answer (score 0):

Thank's,
I use it with `file.write(word['value'].encode("utf-8"))` and it work too :)

But you can try with `file.encode('utf8')` if it's not for write something